# Add new array at the beginning of multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array like this:

```
    // Create an empty array
    $noti_log = array();

    // Add first array within a multidimensional array
    $noti_log = array(
        array('hello world')
    );
```

And then, when I want to add a new array inside, I do:

```
$noti_log[] = array('Greetings');
```

The problem is that whenever I add a new array, it ends up underneath the old ones. Instead, I want new arrays to line up **on top of the old ones**.

So in this case, `array('Greetings')` should be on top of `array('hello world')`...

How do I add new arrays that land on top?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php after you insert normally

Comment: What is better to use? Array reverse or array_unshift?

Comment: Depends, `array_reverse` reverses the entire array.  Not what you asked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`array_unshift()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php):

> array_unshift() prepends passed elements to the front of the array. Note that the list of elements is prepended as a whole, so that the prepended elements stay in the same order. All numerical array keys will be modified to start counting from zero while literal keys won't be touched.

```
array_unshift($noti_log, array('Greetings'));
```